# integrating redux in facebook login with react

Tags: reactjs, facebook

I am facing this issue where once the user has logged in ,I need to save the user to my reducers so I am dispatching actions but i am getting error as the loginUser cannot be dispatched .
Here is the code .Look at teestApi part where I have called the action with userProfile .
Where should we call it if not here ?I am getting the error cannot read property loginUser and i see some facebook sdk .
I am also getting this error of window.Fb is not defined on firefox browser.

```
     class SocialLogin extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        userData:""
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    window.fbAsyncInit = ()=> {
        window.FB.init({
            appId: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            autoLogAppEvents: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v3.0'
        });

        window.FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', response => {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                this.checkLoginState();
            } else {
                console.log('[FacebookLoginButton] User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        });
    };
}

checkLoginState(){
    window.FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        this.statusChangeCallback(response);
    }.bind(this));
}

login(){
    window.FB.login(this.checkLoginState(), {scope: 'email'});
}

statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log("response",response);
    debugger
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        this.testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        console.log("[FacebookLoginButton] Person is logged into Facebook but not your app");
    } else {
        console.log("[FacebookLoginButton] Person is not logged into Facebook");
    }
}

testAPI() {
    let userProfile;
    window.FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        const photoUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com/${response.id}/picture?type=large`;
       userProfile = {
              id:response.id,
              name:response.name,
              photo: photoUrl,
              provider: "Facebook"
            };
            console.log("userProfile",userProfile);



        console.log('[FacebookLoginButton] Successful login for: ', response);
    });

    this.setState({
        userData:userProfile
    },()=>{
        console.log("userData",this.state.userData);
    }); 
    this.props.loginUser(userProfile);
     window.location.href=" https://" ;//commented this part

}

render(){
    return (
        <button className="btn btn-block btn-fb" onClick={()=>this.login()}>
            <i className="fa fa-facebook"/> Connect with Facebook
        </button>
    )
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  }
            export default connect(
           null,
           { loginUser }
        )(SocialLogin);
```

Comment: what is the exact error message? you should use class properties with arrow functions, or you will have problems with the context. that way, you don´t need that workaround anymore, for example: onClick={()=>this.login()}

Comment: cannot read property loginuser of undefined

Comment: this.props is undefined then. probably a context issue then, use arrow functions.